# update a property of field in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, mongo-collection, database

I have a collection `Task` in which I have a field `title` as unique = True, but due to latest requirement this unique = True has to be removed, i.e. it has to be set as False.

Is there a way to do this ?
Ofcourse I don't want to drop my collection.

Comment: as unique you mean index on the title field being unique? Better to fix description on your question and title if that is the case

Comment: I have define my task datamodel something like this: 
title = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=128, unique=True)

it's not about the indexes.

Comment: My bad just realized 'mongoengine' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your model code and remove index from collection. See specification: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/. Do not forgot make backup.